# Authenticating a dummy service with CAS authentication in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, authentication, cas

I'm trying to make a web app that used CAS authentication from my college to log a user in. The backend is written using Express, running on `localhost:5000` for now. I have used the `cas-authentication` package to handle the authentication for me. Using the example code from its npm page:

```js
var app = require('express')();
var session = require('express-session');
var CASAuthentication = require('cas-authentication');
 
// Set up an Express session, which is required for CASAuthentication.
app.use( session({
    secret            : 'super secret key',
    resave            : false,
    saveUninitialized : true
}));
 
// Create a new instance of CASAuthentication.
var cas = new CASAuthentication({
    cas_url     : 'https://my-cas-host.com/cas',
    service_url : 'https://my-service-host.com'
});
 
// Unauthenticated clients will be redirected to the CAS login and then back to
// this route once authenticated.
app.get( '/app', cas.bounce, function ( req, res ) {
    res.send( '<html><body>Hello!</body></html>' );
});
 
// Unauthenticated clients will receive a 401 Unauthorized response instead of
// the JSON data.
app.get( '/api', cas.block, function ( req, res ) {
    res.json( { success: true } );
});
 
// An example of accessing the CAS user session variable. This could be used to
// retrieve your own local user records based on authenticated CAS username.
app.get( '/api/user', cas.block, function ( req, res ) {
    res.json( { cas_user: req.session[ cas.session_name ] } );
});
 
// Unauthenticated clients will be redirected to the CAS login and then to the
// provided "redirectTo" query parameter once authenticated.
app.get( '/authenticate', cas.bounce_redirect );
 
// This route will de-authenticate the client with the Express server and then
// redirect the client to the CAS logout page.
app.get( '/logout', cas.logout );

app.listen(5000);
```

My question is, if I put the url of my college's CAS portal as `cas_url` in the `CASAuthentication` object, then what should I put in the `service_url`?

I tried putting `localhost:5000` there, but when I launch the app and go to `localhost:5000/app`, it redirects me to a page that says "Application not authorized to use CAS". Instead, putting in the moodle site for my college in its place doesn't give this issue and redirects to moodle after authentication (Our college's Moodle also uses CAS).

I understand that this is some kind of security feature to keep malicious services from using CAS, but does this mean that every service that is still in early development stages must be registered with CAS?
Or is there some kind of work around that I can use without needing to talk to the college admins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [CAS documentation](https://apereo.github.io/cas/6.2.x/installation/Troubleshooting-Guide.html#application-not-authorized):

> You may encounter this error, when the requesting application/service url cannot be found in your CAS service registry. When an authentication request is submitted to the CAS login endpoint, the destination application is indicated as a url parameter which will be checked against the CAS service registry to determine if the application is allowed to use CAS. If the url is not found, this message will be displayed back. Since service definitions in the registry have the ability to be defined by a url pattern, it is entirely possible that the pattern in the registry for the service definition is misconfigured and does not produce a successful match for the requested application url.

So,

> does this mean that every service that is still in early development stages must be registered with CAS?

Yes. If you want to use someone else's system, you need their permission, regardless.

> Or is there some kind of work around that I can use without needing to talk to the college admins?

There is no workaround. However, you can set up your own CAS server.